# Обновление UI JavaFX во время выполнения

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Есть Label. Я хочу получить следующий алгоритм:

Нажатие на кнопку -> Установить текст("test1") -> что-то делать -> Установить текст("test2").

Но поле нажатия, устанавливается текст "test2".

```
// Action нажатия на кнопку

    Platform.runLater(() -> info.setText("test1"));

// Что-то делаем. (Background задача)
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Platform.runLater(() -> info.setText("test2"));
```

Я даже пробовал создать класс, наследующий от Service, который реализует

```
@Override

protected Task<Void> createTask()
```

В котором я устанавливал текст.

Естественно пробовал info.setText("test1") -> background-задача в отдельном потоке 
 -> info.setText("test2")
Но всё равно не получается. Не могли бы Вы мне подсказать: как в рантайме изменить  элемент интерфейса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс потока:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{

    final Runnable onStopTask;

    public MyThread(Runnable onStopTask) {
        this.onStopTask = onStopTask;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start thread");

        try {
            System.out.println("Do something ...");
            sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        Platform.runLater(onStopTask);

        System.out.println("Stop thread\n");
    }
}
```

Класс приложения:

```
public class ThreadTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            Label first = new Label();
            Label second = new Label();

            Button btn = new Button("Action");

            btn.setOnAction(e->{
                first.setText("First");
                new MyThread(()->second.setText("Second"));
            });

            VBox root = new VBox(20.0, btn, first, second);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде получилось. Если есть рекомендательная литература про потоки и ui в javafx, я бы был признателен.